# Identify items in one list not in another of a different type

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I need to identify items from one list that are not present in another list. The two lists are of different entities (`ToDo` and `WorkshopItem`). I consider a workshop item to be in the todo list if the `Name` is matched in any of the todo list items.

The following does what I'm after but find it awkward and hard to understand each time I revisit it. I use NHibernate `QueryOver` syntax to get the two lists and then a LINQ statement to filter down to just the Workshop items that meet the requirement (`DateDue` is in the next two weeks and the `Name` is not present in the list of ToDo items.

```
var allTodos = Session.QueryOver<ToDo>().List();
var twoWeeksTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14);
var workshopItemsDueSoon = Session.QueryOver<WorkshopItem>()
                                  .Where(w => w.DateDue <= twoWeeksTime).List();

var matches = from wsi in workshopItemsDueSoon
              where !(from todo in allTodos
                      select todo.TaskName)
                    .Contains(wsi.Name)
              select wsi;
```

Ideally I'd like to have just one NHibernate query that returns a list of `WorkshopItem`s that match my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure how to achieve what you need using LINQ so to give you an option I am just putting up an alternative solution using nHibernate Criteria (this will execute in one database hit):

```
// Create a query
ICriteria query = Session.CreateCriteria<WorkShopItem>("wsi");

// Restrict to items due within the next 14 days
query.Add(Restrictions.Le("DateDue", DateTime.Now.AddDays(14));

// Return all TaskNames from Todo's
DetachedCriteria allTodos = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Todo)).SetProjection(Projections.Property("TaskName"));

// Filter Work Shop Items for any that do not have a To-do item 
query.Add(SubQueries.PropertyNotIn("Name", allTodos);

// Return results
var matchingItems = query.Future<WorkShopItem>().ToList()
```

Comment: Nice, one database hit is definitely a good thing. Not keen on the 'magic strings' in the Criteria syntax though. I've got fat fingers and typos are far too easy.

Comment: @SimonMartin agreed, although a sacrifice I am willing to make for performance. Waiting for someone to come along with a Linq version so we can both learn something!

Answer (score 2):

I *think* I've managed to put together a Linq version of the answer put forward by @CSL and will mark that as the accepted answer as it put me in the direction of the following.

```
var twoWeeksTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14);
var subquery = NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver.Of<ToDo>().Select(t => t.TaskName);
var matchingItems = Session.QueryOver<WorkshopItem>()
                           .Where(w => w.DateDue <= twoWeeksTime && 
                                       w.IsWorkshopItemInProgress == true)
                           .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(x => x.Name).NotIn(subquery)
                           .Future<WorkshopItem>();
```

It returns the results I'm expecting and doesn't rely on magic strings. I'm hesitant because I don't fully understand the WithSubquery (and whether inlining it would be a good thing). It seems to equate to

```
WHERE WorkshopItem.Name IS NOT IN (subquery)
```

Also I don't understand the `Future` instead of `List`. If anyone would shed some light on those that would help.

Comment: The `Future` construct basically tells nHibernate to defer execution of the query until a later point in time where ideally nHibernate will have more information to further optimize the query that is constructed and sent to the database. This is a really good post demonstrating the feature http://ayende.com/blog/3979/nhibernate-futures

Comment: Just another note, if you haven't got a copy already, nHibernate Profiler from Hibernating Rhinos is well worth the money to examine and evaluate exactly what SQL is being sent to the database.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend

```
var workshopItemsDueSoon = Session.QueryOver<WorkshopItem>()
                                  .Where(w => w.DateDue <= twoWeeksTime)
var allTodos = Session.QueryOver<ToDo>();
```

Instead of

```
var allTodos = Session.QueryOver<ToDo>().List();
var workshopItemsDueSoon = Session.QueryOver<WorkshopItem>()
                                  .Where(w => w.DateDue <= twoWeeksTime).List();
```

So that the collection isn't iterated until you need it to be.

I've found that it's helpfull to use linq extension methods to make subqueries more readable and less awkward.

For example:

```
var matches = from wsi in workshopItemsDueSoon
              where !allTodos.Select(it=>it.TaskName).Contains(wsi.Name)
              select wsi
```

Personally, since the query is fairly simple, I'd prefer to do it like so:

```
var matches = workshopItemsDueSoon.Where(wsi => !allTodos.Select(it => it.TaskName).Contains(wsi.Name))
```

The latter seems less verbose to me.

Comment: How do you access `wsi` to get the Name in your last code statement without LINQ?

Comment: that was a typo.  I apologize.  I'll edit the code to correct it.  Just so you know, this actually is linq, but I've used the extension methods provided by System.Linq, rather than using the query syntax.  To clarify the code above, the "it" represents each item in the collection.  When linq iterates over the collection, it will apply the logic in the lambda expressions to each item in the collection.  Look up the "Where" and "Select" extension methods if you're not familiar with them.  I find myself using them over and over again.

Comment: correction to above: it was not a typo.  the wsi in the "Where" function, is like the "it" in the "Select" function.  The wsi is the name I gave to the parameter of the lambda expression, because it's doing the same thing you were doing before with wsi.